# Title and affiliations FLUSH LEFT in pdf of manuscript written with papaja

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio, papaja

I need to submit a manuscript originally written with `papaja` with the title and affiliations flush left (and ideally the title in bold). I've searched all over and can't seem to find a solution - I think the latex options are overwritten by `papaja`. Any suggestions? The YAML is below.

```
---
title             : "The paper title"
shorttitle        : "running head"

author: 
  - name          : "First Author"
    affiliation   : "1"
  
affiliation:
  - id            : "1"
    institution   : "Department of Science"

floatsintext      : no
figurelist        : yes
tablelist         : no
footnotelist      : no
linenumbers       : no
mask              : no
draft             : no
documentclass     : "apa6"
classoption       : "doc, donotrepeattitle" # suppresses title on 1st page of MS
output: papaja::apa6_pdf
---




# Methods
We report how we determined our sample size, all data exclusions (if any), all manipulations, and all measures in the study. <!-- 21-word solution (Simmons, Nelson & Simonsohn, 2012; retrieved from http://ssrn.com/abstract=2160588) -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Aaaaaand of course I tried something after posting that worked. Leaving here instead of deleting in case it helps others.

```
# Title and Affiliations flush left
title: "\\flushleft The paper title."
```

```
# Title and Affiliations flush left, Title bold
title: "\\flushleft \\textbf{The paper title.}"
```